# Wordpress on Sub Directory with Nginx using Proxy Pass with No Input File error

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, proxy

Hope you can help but I am getting error below when trying to access the admin section of are blog.

> No input file specified.

The actual blog is working fine but not the login/admin areas.

As per the title the blog is on a seperate server to are main domain and were using proxy pass to forward requests to it like so.

```
upstream blog {
    server 111.111.111.111:443 weight=2 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=60s;
}

server{
  ...
  location /blog {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://blog;
    }
}
```

The nginx settings I have on the blog server is as follows.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    root /home/www.domain.com/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.domain.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Here are the fastcgi_params if it helps as well.

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;
fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https if_not_empty;
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
fastcgi_param   HTTP_PROXY  "";
```

I understand I believe that PHP cant find the index.php file?

Hope someone can help..

Comment: Is `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` exists in `fastcgi_params`?

Comment: Yes. If you refresh I have added whats in there.

Comment: Is requests to second server directly work fine? And error only if requested via first server?

Comment: Yea.  If I change my hosts file to work with it directly it works. I think thats what you are asking..

Comment: Cant see any troubles (except better to use `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`). May be trouble in skipped part of first config.

Comment: Have tried that. Still same error..

Comment: Is there anything in the NGINX access and error logs?

Comment: Can you show full config of first server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was the upstream was not allowing for any other params ie extension .php,  this was the upstream location change..

```
location ^~ /blog {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass https://blog;
}
```

Hopes this helps anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify just `index index.php;`.

You should also change

```
location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$query_string; }
```

to

```
location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args; }
```

and change:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
```

to:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
fastcgi_pass php;
```

This is coming from the [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx) as well as the [NGINX documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/).

Answer (score 0):

maybe rewrite the /blog path to supress the prefix?

```
server{
  ...
  location /blog {

        #strip the '/blog' prefix
        rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1  break;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://blog;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry don't understand.  Are you saying to remove the location /blog part?

Comment: I'm saying that you will forward the URLs without the '/blog', ngnix will internally remove that part. When you access /blog/page1 the upstream wordpress server will receive /page1

Comment: Adding that line gives me 403. I removed the /blog prefix within the blog nginx file and still 403

Comment: Well, I'm lost. You probably should check/enable the nginx logs to get more info